# Does changing an img src attribute emit any emitters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, electron

I am working on a page which has images of varying sizes, and I want to change the parent div size in accordance to the new image's height.

I have `inner`, `viewOne` and `viewTwo` set as global variables, and my code is as follows.

```
  viewOne.src = 'path/to/newImage.png';
  viewTwo.src = 'path/to/otherImage.png';

  inner = document.getElementById('innerWindow'); // Parent Div
  viewOne = document.getElementById('viewImgOne'); // Image Object
  viewTwo = document.getElementById('viewImgTwo'); // Image Object

  if(viewOne.clientHeight >= viewTwo.clientHeight) {
    inner.style.height = viewOne.clientHeight + "px";
  } else {
    inner.style.height = viewTwo.clientHeight + "px";
  };
```

The parent div doesn't always resize itself properly after changing image paths, so there might be a few hundred pixels left over in the bottom of the div that shouldn't be there at time.

I also have a `window.onresize` function to resize the div if the browser window changes, and it works as intended.

Is there a way to watch `src`, and run the resize function after the image fully loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this problem is to bind the .load event for all images and then you will know when the image has finished loading, after a src change.  I'm not sure if there is a more direct way to observe src changes.  However, for this to work consistently, you need to bind .load before anything touches the image element's .src.

If you are creating the image elements dynamically that shouldn't be a problem, or if you are re-using the same image tags over and over that shouldn't be an issue (besides for the initial first load on page load, but you probably don't need to worry about that?)

Comment: The page starts out with the `<img>` tags empty.  How could I implement this into my project?

Comment: You could use querySelector to get all img tags and then use a forEach() to iterate over each element and then addEventListener('load', fn) where fn will be called whenever an image finishes loading (the this object inside of fn will b the image element.)

Comment: I used this based on your suggestion and it works great!

    `var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
      images[j].addEventListener('load', imgDivResizer());
    }`